# Laravel Localization AngularJS $scope

Tags: angularjs, laravel, localization

In my view I'm returning data fom AngularJS $scope using following syntaxis `@{{item.status}}` 
$scope contains following strings: -1,0,1,2 
I have no problem localize default strings but how can I localize $scope? Read Laravel documentation and found nothing...
Btw I'm using mcamara localization package

Tried this

```
 {{ __('auth.-1',['item.status' => @{{item.status}}]) }}
 {!! __('auth.@{{item.status}}') !!}
 {{ __('auth.@{{item.status}}') }}
 @lang('auth.@{{bet.status}}')
```

Comment: Please provide some code that doesn't work in simpliest form

Comment: @zmii updated question